# Is it safe/sensible to store utensils above the hob?

Tags: storage-method, utensils

I have a rack of hooks that sit on the wall that my cooker backs on to, and on this I hang a crowded collection various utensils:

[image: Photo of various utensils hanging directly above electric hob surface]

The space is fairly contained, as there are cupboards on either side and the fan/extractor unit directly above. While cooking some pasta earlier they were getting a *heavy* steaming, which got me thinking... **is this storage location safe and/or sensible in terms of hygiene and degradation of the tools? Or any other considerations?**

---

For those without access to the image, or want more info without guessing, the rack holds (in order):

- Two metal handle/clip things for the oven's grill tray
- Metal/Plastic potato masher
- Metal/Plastic spatula
- Plastic spatula
- Plastic slotted spoon
- Plastic spoon
- Metal whisk
- Wooden spatula
- Metal tongs
- Metal/Plastic tongs
- Metal/Plastic Can opener

Answer (score 4):

This really should be a comment, as it doesn't directly answer the question, but it's kinda long ...

I do the same thing, but I'll admit there are a couple of disadvantages:

1. When you stir-fry, you will aresolize oils which will end up depositing on the utensils (and pot racks above your stove).
2. Some things will splatter (eg, a long-simmering tomato sauce), which again means the need to wash the utensils.

As for the degredation issues -- if they can't even handle the temperature of steaming, you probably don't want them in the kitchen at all.  I haven't notice any problems with my wooden or wood-handled utensils.

I don't have any better space, as my cabinets are so low that hanging utensils can't really fit anywhere else in the kitchen, and I find hanging so much more convenient than everything in a drawer or a container on the counter that I'm not willing to switch.

Are there safety issues?  Maybe if there were a fire on the stove, but so long as it isn't the fire extinguisher being stored there, I don't think it's that big of an issue.  (that's not to say that I know for sure there aren't any ... I just don't know of any)

Comment: It's very much a lack-of-space issue for me as well.  And I was thinking of "safety" more in terms of food safety wrt contamination etc, but I the potential (or not) for them causing or exacerbating a fire  (or injury, or anything else) is a valid point for discussion as well. As for degradation, one thought that jumps to mind is if metallic objects maybe being more prone to rust?

Answer (score 4):

That's not a good place from a safety aspect - reaching over the hob will be hazardous during cooking.

The gizmos will get coated with undesirable gunge unless all are in everyday use - a film will be picked up from cooking vapours, which will then trap dust and microorganisms.

It is not a good idea ...

Comment: Reaching is less of a problem - I tend to "preselect" my tools before starting - and "undesirable gunge" was my real concern. But is it realistically worth being concerned about? I mean, I've had them (well, there were less to start with) hanging there for almost five years now and it hasn't killed me yet....